# How to show print dialog box and print preview on same screen?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word, print-preview

I am trying to emulate <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> in Excel 2013 where the print dialog box is shown on the left with the print preview on the right.

(Although where the preview displays, I always have to click **"Show Print Preview"** first. I can't find a way to force the preview to show every time).

I tried the following:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

This shows the old style dialog box where you need to click the "Preview" button

```
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
```

This shows the preview but doesn't allow the printer to be changed from the same screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Something like this?*

***Excel***

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
End Sub
```

*[CommandBars.ExecuteMso Method (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx)*  *is useful method in cases where there is no object model for a particular command.*

***For Outlook***

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector

    If Not Inspector Is Nothing Then
        Dim cmd As Office.CommandBars
        Set cmd = Inspector.CommandBars

        cmd.ExecuteMso ("FilePrintPreview")
    Else
        ActiveExplorer.selection(1).Display
        Set cmd = ActiveInspector.CommandBars
        cmd.ExecuteMso ("FilePrintPreview")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes thanks!  I am surprised I couldn't find that anywhere, would have thought more people would have wanted to do the same.

Comment: No need for parentheses around the text in quotes, so use `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PrintPreviewAndPrint"`, despite what the macro recorder and the online documentation show.